# How do I Auto Compile In Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and I want to know is there an easier/faster way to compile my code? I don't want to be typing this into terminal (i.e `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp main.cpp -std::c++11 -lcurl -o FileCPP`) every single time.

Comment: You could use `make`.

Comment: Thank you. That was insanely simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hay Man I unterstoord Your Problem You Can Try This:
1)write a bash script to automate all this c programs
Program :
`#!/bin/bash g++ [programname].cpp -o [outputname] | ./[outputname]`
2)and if you want more to automate then you can add this script to cronjobs Then this will run for ever certain time you have set To!